# Can't play dvd with movie player

Tags: 11.04, dvd, plugins

When I try to open a dvd with movie player, I get a message saying that a plugin is missing. It isn't specified what plugin is needed and when I click on the `search` button, no appropriate plugin is found.

How do I determine what I need? What is the best way to view DVDs on Ubuntu 11.04?

Answer (score 3):

*by abarbaneld*

Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal does not come out of the box playing DVDs but with 2 simple commands you will be watching DVDs in a flash.

1. Open a Terminal Window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`
3. Type `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`
4. Insert DVD and enjoy.

I noticed during playback of my DVD that the picture was a bit wobbly. There is an easy fix for this.

Go to **Edit>Preferences>Display** Tab and check the box that reads disable deinterlacing of interlaced videos.
Next close down the Movie Player and reopen it and the wobbly screen should be gone.

[image]

Another option that is worth enabling is the play video where you left off.
Go to **Edit>Preferences>General** Tab and check on Start playing files from last position.

[image]

Comment: If you have suggestions to how to fix the mess I've described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/50877/help-i-broke-apt-get-with-partial-install-of-ubuntu-restricted-extras I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Open software center and search for: ubuntu-restricted-extras install it.
Also it should work in VLC player, try it.

Answer (score 1):

And if you keep having a message stating the decrypt lib are not installed or if VLC starts reading the media and stops, it is because your region is not correct for the DVD. To fix this, download regionset using packet manager.