# Cannot install any software from the Software Center due to ttf-mscorefonts-installer package error

Tags: package-management, software-center

When I try to install any software from ubuntu software center it comes with error:

```
An unhandled error occured
There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon. This is the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package management related tasks.
details
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 961, in simulate
    trans.unauthenticated = self._simulate_helper(trans)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1085, in _simulate_helper
    return depends, self._cache.required_download, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 226, in required_download
    pm.get_archives(fetcher, self._list, self._records)
SystemError: E:I wasn't able to locate file for the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 10):

Possibly this error was caused when you interrupted the install or removal of Wine.

Try running the following in a terminal session:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Edit:

When you see in the terminal window appear 
"Package configuration -

```
┌─────────────────┤ Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer ├─────────────────┐
```

press tab or I think the arrow keys until the "OK" is highlighted.

Then press Enter to accept the license agreement

- [How can I accept the Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

Comment: Running 1st command - dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process

Comment: Running 2nd command -  Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Running 3rd command - E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: 2nd and 3rd command worked. after running 3rd in a terminal window appear Package configuration -  ┌─────────────────┤ Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer ├─────────────────┐
After I read the license agreement can just close the terminal window, but it says - There is still a process running in this terminal. Closing the terminal will kill it.        I think thats where problem first appeared. When I installed wine I had the same window and I just closed it. What do I do with this window?

Comment: Make sure you do not have synaptic manager running.  With regards to the license agreement window - press tab or I think the arrow keys until the "OK" is highlighted.  Then press Enter to accept the license agreement.

Comment: excellent news - please click the tick button to accept the answer

Comment: The OP seems to have forgotten to tick this answer, but it works perfectly. I just ran into this problem today. When I came to the **Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer** EULA screen, I couldn't figure out how to choose "Ok" (all you have to do is press `tab`) so I closed the terminal. Afterward, I couldn't install _anything_. @fossfreedom's method fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ubuntu are you running? (I would add this as a comment to your question but I can't find the button.)

The error message seems to suggest it is just a bug in aptdaemon or software-center, which you might want to repot over at bugs.ubuntu.com.

What you might do is run Synaptic Package Manager and, under Custom Filters in the bottom left-hand corner, click the Broken filter on the left-hand side, and try to reinstall all packages, if any, that come up.

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04     Can not run Synaptic Package Manager. It comes with an error - Unable to get exclusive lock

This usually means that another package management application (like apt-get or aptitude) is already running.  Please close that application first.                        Everything seems to be closed.

Comment: You might want to add the version number to your question :)

Have you tried running Synaptic first thing after you start up your computer?