# aptdaemon error: cannot install any packages 

Tags: installation, 11.10, apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot install any software from the Software Center due to mss-ttcoreconts package error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57101/cannot-install-any-software-from-the-software-center-due-to-mss-ttcoreconts-pack)

I'm trying to install packages and I get this error:

> There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package management related tasks.

and the details:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 968, in silmulate
    trans.unauthenticated = self._simulate_helper(trans)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1092, in _simulate_helper
    return depends, self._cache.required_download, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 235, in required_download
    pm.get_archives(fetcher, self._list, self._records)
SystemError: E:I wasn't able to locate a file for the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.
```

How do I resolve this error?