# An unhandleable error occurred

Tags: software-center, wine, apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot install any software from the Software Center due to ttf-mscorefonts-installer package error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57101/cannot-install-any-software-from-the-software-center-due-to-ttf-mscorefonts-inst)

Ubuntu 11.10

Software Centre

Error title:An unhandlable error occured

Error Body:

```
 There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package management related tasks.

Details: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 968, in simulate
    trans.unauthenticated = self._simulate_helper(trans)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1092, in _simulate_helper
    return depends, self._cache.required_download, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 235, in required_download
    pm.get_archives(fetcher, self._list, self._records)
SystemError: E:I wasn't able to locate a file for the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.
```

What should I do?
Sorry if this has been posted before.

Comment: please add the output of `sudo apt-get -f install` followed by `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue myself. It was an issue with a botched install of a fonts package. I will delete the question shortly. Thanks for your input though. I realized what the problem was almost immediately after posting. It was the mss-ttcorefonts package.

I went into synaptic and went into the list of broken packages. I renistalled and have no problems now.

Comment: IMO that would be a bad thing to do. I myself stumbled upon the question following the exact same error message.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me today and got solved. Unfor. I didn't catch the whole process... I issued the first command fossfreedom suggested. It returned 1 package not updated. Then the second - one package got updated, software center wouldn't even start after that. I used sudo apt-get install clipit to install something and see what's going on (without using the USC). Clipit got installed no problem. I restarted my computer and now it's all fine. Sorry for not being any more helpful and thank you fossfreedom for your input!