# Programming error in aptdaemon, how to fix it?

Tags: installation, apt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot install any software from the Software Center due to ttf-mscorefonts-installer package error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57101/cannot-install-any-software-from-the-software-center-due-to-ttf-mscorefonts-inst)

I've been trying to install some applications like Skype and Windows, yet same error message keeps showing

> There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package management related tasks.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 968, in simulate
    trans.unauthenticated = self._simulate_helper(trans)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1092, in _simulate_helper
    return depends, self._cache.required_download, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 235, in required_download
    pm.get_archives(fetcher, self._list, self._records)
SystemError: E:I wasn't able to locate a file for the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package.
```

> This might mean you need to manually fix this package.

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu and couldn't get it fix. I tried to search for similar questions yet couldn't really fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the error:

> E:I wasn't able to locate a file for the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package.

Try to reconfigure unpacked packages first.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And then install it:

```
sudo aptitude install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```