# can't download from ubuntu software center

Tags: package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot install any software from the Software Center due to ttf-mscorefonts-installer package error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57101/cannot-install-any-software-from-the-software-center-due-to-ttf-mscorefonts-inst)

I'm a linux first timer. The first few days everything was running fine but then when y try to download someting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 968, in simulate
    trans.unauthenticated = self._simulate_helper(trans)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1092, in _simulate_helper
    return depends, self._cache.required_download, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 235, in required_download
    pm.get_archives(fetcher, self._list, self._records)
SystemError: E:I wasn't able to locate a file for the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.
```

PSD: I'm a windows user trying linux. I don't know anything about terminals. Thanks

Comment: please can you type the following into a terminal and copy & paste the output into an edit of your question:  `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

go to terminal

type in sudo apt-get install synaptic
put in your password
tell it yes, you want to download and install
after complete
type exit
find synaptic package manager
use the command from the menu, fix broken packages
this should fix any broken packages causing the error

Answer (score 0):

If you already have Synaptic installed, you can find it in the Settings or System menu.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't want to install Synaptic, you can configure any half configured packages and install missing dependencies which might be causing the problem. Press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and search for and start the *Terminal*.

Now run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If it still doesn't sort out your issue, try re-install Software Center by:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```