# Cannot install using Software Center - fix does not work

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, dpkg, users

The Ubuntu Software Center no longer lets me install software (tried to install pdfsam, and Synaptic, both give the same error):

> There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package management related tasks.
>
> Details:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 325, in _process_transaction
>       self._apply_changes(trans)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/pkcompat.py", line 3157, in _apply_changes
>       install_range)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1151, in _apply_changes
>       with self._frozen_status():
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 59, in **enter**
>       return next(self.gen)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1175, in _frozen_status
>       frozen_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix="aptdaemon-frozen-status")
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tempfile.py", line 426, in mkdtemp
>       dir = gettempdir()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tempfile.py", line 370, in gettempdir
>       tempdir = _get_default_tempdir()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tempfile.py", line 312, in _get_default_tempdir
>       dirlist)
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No usable temporary directory found in ['/tmp', '/var/tmp', '/usr/tmp', '/']

I found and tried this fix, which is featured in all the threads I could find on this problem: [Cannot install any software from the Software Center due to ttf-mscorefonts-installer package error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57101/cannot-install-any-software-from-the-software-center-due-to-ttf-mscorefonts-inst)

The command  sudo dpkg --configure -a
does not work. Output:

> sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/andreas/5: No such file or directory
>
> dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: Read-only file system

Now, I am a Linux-newbie. Before Ubuntu I have used Linux Mint 15, then 16. There the system frequently froze, in particular during installation of new software via apt-get or the software center, which, upon restart, somehow screwed up my user rights (what seems to be the case here, too?) and file system. To fix it I had to reinstall Mint (repeatedly).

Some more background: A few days ago Ubuntu froze, and over lots of waiting (it didn't recover) I found the solution online: [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

> If it locks up completely, you can REISUB it, which is a safer alternative to just cold rebooting the computer.

Could this have caused the problem? Before that, Software Center worked just fine.

I switched from Mint to Ubuntu under the impression that Ubuntu is more stable and less "tinkery" than Mint. I really really don't want to switch back to Windows, but I need my laptop to work, and work reliably; thesis deadline is coming closer.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: try doing: sudo mount -o rw,remount

Comment: Then do what you were trying to do

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean? first command: sudo mount -o rw

Comment: and second command: remount

Comment: the command is **sudo mount -o rw,remount /** exactly like that with the comma, and the slash. It is basically mounting your files in read write mode instead of read only, which should allow you to do **sudo dpkg-reconfigure**

Comment: I see; so that command remounts the root / in rw

Comment: but also this command cannot be executed: sudo: unable to open /var/lib/sudo/andreas/5: No such file or directory
mount: cannot remount block device /dev/sdb5 read-write, is write-protected  (edit: Ubuntu is mounted on sdb5, boot loader is installed on sdb, swap on sdb1, /home is mounted on the separate sda drive

Comment: Ah okay so before you do either of those commands do **sudo umount /dev/sdb5**

Comment: That did the trick! Meanwhile a second error occurred during booting (about problem finding drivers for / ), but I'll start another thread in case I cannot find a solution to it; I don't think it is related to this problem. Thanks a lot, David!

Comment: Any time man, just ask. Now if you have any driver issues, I'd love to still try to help and support

Answer (score 1):

The solution by David (see above) did the trick.
In case anyone stumbles upon this thread with the same problem, here the summary (credits to David and the author of the thread linked in the problem description):

> sudo umount /dev/sdb5

replace [sdb5] with whatever partition your root / is mounted on. Note: it might complain that / is busy, ignore and proceed

> sudo mount -o rw,remount /
>
> sudo dpkg --configure -a
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade